# YAML - intersection of arrays

Tags: yaml, ansible

In the main.yaml file of an Ansible playbook, I have the following play:

```
- name: configure client
  include: client-configuration.yml
  when: "'a' in group_names or 'b' in group_names or 'c' in group_names or 'd' in group_names or 'e' in group_names or 'f' in group_names or 'g' in group_names or 'h' in group_names or 'i' in group_names or 'j' in group_names..."
```

this continues for a while. Ideally, I would like to create an array that contains a, b, c, etc. and returns true if the intersection of my array and group_names has >0 elements, and return false otherwise. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the intersection of two lists use the [intersect filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters). To get the length of a list use the [length filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length).

Your condition then can look like this:

```
- name: configure client
  include: client-configuration.yml
  when: group_names | intersect(myList) | length
```

Comment: That seems to work! Just for clarification, using `| length` in a `when` statement like this is boolean in that 0 is false and all positive values are true?

Comment: Yes, 0 is falsy and any other length would be truthy. But you as well could write it explicitly if you prefer `... | length > 0`

Answer (score 3):

I find this approach a little more readable than the `| length` approach.

```
- when: "['grp1', 'grp2', 'grp3'] | intersect(group_names) | count > 0"
```